# Writing the stream returned by node-fetch

Tags: javascript, stream, node-fetch

the README contains the following code as an example of writing a file fetched:

```
fetch('https://assets-cdn.github.com/images/modules/logos_page/Octocat.png')
    .then(res => {
        const dest = fs.createWriteStream('./octocat.png');
        res.body.pipe(dest);
    });
```

to which I would concatenate another `.then()` to use the file written to disk.  in reality it appears that my code runs before the file has finished writing to disk, so it occurs to me that the promise returned by the above code should take into consideration the issuance of the 'end' event on the stream.  maybe something like this:

```
fetch(url).then(res => new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    const dest = fs.createWriteStream(fn);
    res.body.pipe(dest);
    res.body.on('end', () => resolve());
    dest.on('error', reject);
}));
```

but when I try to run this code it complains:

> TypeError: res.body.on is not a function

which makes sense given that `res.body` looks like this:

```
{ pipe: [Function: pipe] }
```

which is to say, is not a stream at all

two questions:
1) how can I get access to the actual stream?
2) if I have no access to it, how can I know when the read stream has closed so I can resolve?

**p.s.**

and no, I can't get the stream from `.pipe()`, which returns undefined

Answer (score 23, accepted):

As far as I can tell, your code is correct. I ran

```
const fs = require("fs");
const fetch = require("node-fetch");

fetch("https://assets-cdn.github.com/images/modules/logos_page/Octocat.png")
  .then(
    res =>
      new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        const dest = fs.createWriteStream("./tmp.txt");
        res.body.pipe(dest);
        res.body.on("end", () => resolve("it worked"));
        dest.on("error", reject);
      })
  )
  .then(x => console.log(x));
```

and it worked exactly as expected and printed `"it worked"`

Comment: maybe it has to do with the version of node.js... I'm running 11.5.0 and it breaks as I indicated

Comment: @ekkis Hmm I'm on `v11.12.0`. It breaks even if you copy-paste the above and run it?

Comment: I tested it.  it worked.  I'm a bit confused how that could be.  looking into it... thanks

Comment: I found my problem.  it was a bad mock in the tests.  thank you for following up on this

Comment: there is async version ?

Comment: Great answer, thank you ; Do you know how to get the `content-type response header` of the `res.body`?

Comment: Hi, I am trying to return the binary data once node finishes reading it. Can you tell me how to do it?

Answer (score 11):

I figured it out. the writeable stream will automatically close when the readable does. so I can hook onto that instead:

```
fetch(url).then(res => new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    const dest = fs.createWriteStream(fn);
    res.body.pipe(dest);
    dest.on('close', () => resolve());
    dest.on('error', reject);
}));
```

Comment: just wanted to add `fn` is filename in the above example